# why it is showing error "Document is empty"

Tags: jquery, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me why  it is showing error "Document is empty"

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/TN1BN5Yao5Z63RDcBGlN?p=preview

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="second.xsl"></xsl:import>
    <xsl:template name="dosomething">
        <xsl:text>A function that does something</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="dosomething"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="dosomething"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="abc"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why did you tag this XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us everything and you haven't said exactly what you are doing (what is the "it" in the question title, for example?).

But if the link to pinkr.co is your XML input, then the error is that the XML input isn't well-formed - it contains a start tag and no end tag.